# Decrypt PHP's mcrypt_encrypt in MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption

I have PHP encrypting data and saving it to a table inside a Microsoft SQL Server using the `mcrypt_encrypt` function. I'm wondering if it's possible to decrypt the data from the table through SQL Server?

I'm familiar with the `ENCRYPTBYKEY` and `DECRYPTBYKEY` functions, but am unable to use that because this SQL Server is shared and restricts creating certificates/keys.

I was hoping there would be a function like MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` so the key can be specified as a string, but I'm not seeing one so I'm resorting to PHP to encrypt.

Comment: Any alternative ideas are welcome too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this without PHP. I found functions EncryptByPassphrase and DecryptByPassphrase in MS SQL that will suit my needs.